# Combining Restapi and Websockets

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I have a rest api server which makes call to some other Apis,I am accessing the data I get from the server on a react js frontend,But for certain usecases I need to fetch real time data from backed,is there any way do this together,below is my code

```
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_cors import CORS
from tuya_connector import TuyaOpenAPI, TUYA_LOGGER

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.get("/api/device/<string:deviceid>")

def getdata(deviceid):
    ACCESS_ID = ""
    ACCESS_KEY = ""
    API_ENDPOINT = ""

    # Enable debug log

    # Init OpenAPI and connect
    openapi = TuyaOpenAPI(API_ENDPOINT, ACCESS_ID, ACCESS_KEY)
    openapi.connect()

    # Set up device_id
    DEVICE_ID = deviceid

    # Call APIs from Tuya
    # Get the device information
    response = openapi.get("/v1.0/devices/{}".format(DEVICE_ID))
    return response
```

I want to have traditional request response service along with real time data fetching

Answer (score 0):

Websockets endpoints are exactly what you're looking for. If that is not too late, I'd recommend switching to FastAPI which supports WebSockets "natively" (out-of-the-box) - [https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/)

If you need to keep using Flask, there are a few packages that allow you to add WebSockets endpoints: https://flask-sock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

With FastAPI, this is that simple:

```
@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return {"msg": "This is a regular HTTP endpoint"}


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply,I am not exactly sure how to implement this,If you see my code I am calling this open api which takes a parameter deviceid and gives the device data back according to the deviceid,from frontend different device id can be sent for to get different data,why i need also real time is beacuse the state of the device maybe changed manually,for example if its a light it can be turn on or off manually,and I need to show that on my frontend without refreshing the page,from my frontend I can also turn on/off the device which will be a post request